# import images from one server to another

Tags: wordpress

I want to download images from cpanel server. I knew the folder containing images but zipping the folder had already took too much time almost 4-5 hour but still not completed as folder size is too large. So please suggest me the other way to download images.

Comment: Would you want to store images to another server Or your local storage?

Comment: @maulik to another server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you use CPanel on the Drupal server, a solution is to allow a remote MySQL connection.**

1. go into the Cpanel of the Drupal server.
2. go down to Database section and click “Remote MySQL”
3. There you can add an access host (WordPress host). Enter the access host as the SOME-WEBSITE-DOMAIN-OR-IP-ADDRESS and click add host.

**OR**

You can also use the plugin **([FG Drupal to WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-drupal-to-wp/))** for import the data from drupal server to wordpress server.

Now, You can follow the steps ,

Step #1: Install and activate the FG Drupal to WordPress plugin

Step #2: Find out your Drupal database parameters

Step #3: Import your Drupal content into WordPress

For more information, go through the link - [Import/Migrate Drupal to WordPress](https://themeisle.com/blog/migrate-drupal-to-wordpress/)

Thanks!

Comment: thanx for suggesting but actually i want to import from images in drupal server

Comment: That's means you want to import the images drupal server to wordpress server right??

Comment: thnx i wil try to do

Answer (score 0):

cpanel -> Backup Wizard ->Backup -> Full Backup

and download Full Backup

All files are compressed ready to download

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue resolved?
Or you can try one more way.
1> read folder of your existing server.

```
if (file_exists('http://www.---.com/images/'))
```

2> run the loop for files that you have on server.
3> create cron file in WordPress root directory to save the image from URL.

Pros: your process will run on the server so once you run URL in cron the process will never terminate by the web page. This process can be reused in the future if needed.